# Why is test >= 0 true when test is null?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following javascript code:

```js
const test = null

if ( test >= 0 ){
    console.log("Hello World")
}
```

This code will print `Hello World`... In my mind, it should work only if `test === null`. But all the times that I use the condition `test >= 0` the code falls on it. Is there any reason why it happens? I see it as a problem in some situations... For example on the next code:

```js
const test = null

if ( test >= 0 ){
    console.log("1")
} 
else if ( test === null ){
    console.log("Hello World")
}
```

In this case, the code is not doing what apparently it should be doing. The workaround to make it work would be having the habit of always putting the `=== null` condition at first on if/else or switch/cases. Is that how I'm supposed to work with Javascript? Or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: "*Is that how I'm supposed to work with Javascript?*" - no, you're not supposed to use `null` in comparisons with numbers at all :-)

Comment: JS tries to cast types, so if you run `+null` (to convert to int) then you'll get `0`, which is `>= 0`.

Comment: `Or is there a better way of doing it?` → yes, and it called [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any reason why it happens?

Any value that is compared to a number will be coerced to a number<sup>1</sup>. `Number(null)` is `0`, and `0 >= 0` is `true`. If you had used `undefined` on the other hand, you'd have gotten `NaN >= 0` which is `false`.

<sub>1: In fact, the only non-numeric relational comparison is between two strings (or two objects that convert to strings).</sub>

> The workaround to make it work would be having the habit of always putting the `=== null` condition at first.

Yes, that's how to deal with variables that can have the value `null`.

> Or is there a better way of doing it?

You might want to avoid having the value `null` at all in your variable. Depending on the application, whatever the value is representing, could also be expressed as `0` or `-1` maybe? Those may not be much cleaner, but they would at least have predictable behaviour in `>= 0`.

Answer (score 3):

I thought it was a simple question but I was wrong.
I went check ECMAScript Language Specification, which specified how "a>=b" works.

It turned out it is not doing "a>b || a==b", but instead, it is returning the oppsite answer of "a<b".
I think that is why (null >= 0) is returning true, because (null < 0) is returning false.

[ES3 spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-262_3rd_edition_december_1999.pdf)

> 11.8.4 The Greater-than-or-equal Operator ( >= ) The production RelationalExpression : RelationalExpression >= ShiftExpression is
> evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Evaluate RelationalExpression.
> 2. Call GetValue(Result(1)).
> 3. Evaluate ShiftExpression.
> 4. Call GetValue(Result(3)).
> 5. **Perform the comparison Result(2) < Result(4)**. (see 11.8.5).**
> 6. If Result(5) is true or undefined, return false. Otherwise, return true.

And, I found another reference which plots the Relational and Equality Operators of some special cases.

[Relational and Equality Operators](https://thomas-yang.me/projects/oh-my-dear-js/)

Answer (score -5):

if you cast null to bool, you are getting 0.

```
if ( test >= 0 ){
```

Here larger or equal operator using for comparison, so you are getting correct results.

For example

```
Boolean(null); // false
```

For more please check https://javascript.info/ifelse#boolean-conversion

Comment: There's no boolean involved in the OP's code

Comment: It's implicit conversion when comparing two different types.

Comment: Yes, but not to a boolean!

Comment: In the OPs code comparison in if statement performed with 0 which is representation of Boolean false as well. 0 equal to false equal to null - remember.

Comment: But it doesn't matter that both `null` and `0` can be coerced to `false`. That's not happening in the comparison `null >= 0`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).